# Showing the general solution reduces to $x(t)\approx \frac{F}{2mw^2_0\theta}\left(\sin(w_0t)-\sin(wt)\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, approximation, mathematical-physics

> Consider the equation for a periodically forced, damped oscillator:
>   $$m\ddot{x}+r_0\dot{x}+k_0x=F\sin(wt)$$
>   where $m, r_0, k_0$ are positive constants. Suppose now that $r_0=0$ and let $w_0=\sqrt{\frac{k_0}{m}}$.

I have already shown that the general solution to the above ODE satisfying the inital conditions $x(0)=x_0, \ \dot{x}(0)=v_0$ is 
$$x(t)=x_0\cos(w_0t)+\frac{1}{w_0}\left(v_0-\frac{Fw}{m(w^2_0-w^2)}\right)\sin(w_0t)+\frac{F}{m(w^2_0-w^2)}\sin(wt)$$

> Show that is $w\approx w_0$, say if $w=w_0(1+\theta)$ where $|\theta|<<1$, then
>   $$x(t)\approx \frac{F}{2mw^2_0\theta}\left(\sin(w_0t)-\sin(wt)\right)$$

I can't show this result. Substituting $w=w_0(1+\theta)$ and using simple algebra, I am stuck at
$$x(t)=x_0\cos(w_0t)+\sin(w_0t)\left(\frac{v_0}{w_o}+\frac{F}{mw^2_0(2+\theta)}\right)+\frac{F}{mw^2_0\theta(2+\theta)}\left(\sin(w_0t)-\sin(wt)\right)$$

It appears this is just an exercise in algebra, but I'm so stuck. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did the problem let $x_0=0$ and $v_0=0$ ?

Comment: I wish haha the only piece of information similar to that is that of the initial conditions used in order to find the constants of the general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall put my faith in your calculations and believe that
$$x(t)=x_0\cos(w_0t)+\frac{1}{w_0}\left(v_0-\frac{Fw}{m(w^2_0-w^2)}\right)\sin(w_0t)+\frac{F}{m(w^2_0-w^2)}\sin(wt)$$
is true.  Note that we can ignore every term except those with denominator $w_0^2-w^2$ (since this number will be almost $0$, making the terms with this denominator blow up).  Hence,
$$x(t)\approx-\frac{Fw}{mw_0(w_0^2-w^2)}\,\sin(w_0t)+\frac{F}{m(w_0^2-w)}\,\sin(wt)\,.$$
Consequently, note that $w_0^2-w^2=w_0^2-w_0^2(1+\theta)^2\approx -2\theta w_0^2$, where terms with second or higher orders of $\theta$ are neglected.  Thus,
$$x(t)\approx \frac{Fw}{2mw_0^3\theta}\,\sin(w_0t)-\frac{F}{2mw_0^2\theta}\,\sin(wt)\,.\tag{*}$$
As $\dfrac{w}{w_0}\approx 1$, we obtain
$$x(t)\approx \frac{F}{2mw_0^2\theta}\,\sin(w_0t)-\frac{F}{2mw_0^2\theta}\,\sin(wt)\,,\tag{#}$$
which is what we need.

---

**Caveat:**  This estimation is not entirely correct, and I personally would not use it, at least in the small-$t$ limit (namely, $|t|\ll\dfrac{\pi}{2w_0\theta}$).  First, remember when we used the approximation $\dfrac{w}{w_0} \approx 1$.  In fact, we have $\dfrac{w}{w_0}=1+\theta$.  Thus, already, (*) should become
$$x(t)\approx \frac{F}{2mw_0^2}\,\sin(w_0t)+\frac{F}{2mw_0}\,\left(\frac{\sin(w_0t)-\sin(wt)}{w_0\theta}\right)\,.$$
For small $t$, we have
$$\frac{\sin(w_0t)-\sin(wt)}{w_0\theta t}\approx-\cos(w_0t)\,,$$
whence
$$x(t)\approx \frac{F}{2mw_0^2}\,\sin(w_0t)-\frac{Ft}{2mw_0}\,\cos(w_0t)$$
is a better approximation, but then from the $\theta$-independence of this result, the assumption that "we can ignore every term except those with denominator $w_0^2-w^2$ [...]" is no longer valid.  Indeed, we need every other term, and here is a much more correct estimate for small $t$:
$$x(t)\approx x_0\,\cos(w_0t)+\frac{v_0}{w_0}\,\sin(w_0 t)+\frac{F}{2mw_0^2}\,\sin(w_0t)-\frac{Ft}{2mw_0}\,\cos(w_0t)\,.$$

However, for large $t$, the values of $\sin(w_0t)$ and $\sin(wt)$ can be sufficiently large.  Ergo, the approximation (#) is only good for large values of $t$.  In fact, (#) is not even good for all large $t$.  Let $n$ denote the integer closest to $\dfrac{w_0\theta t}{\pi}$ (if there are two of such integers, then you can choose any of them to be $n$).  In the case that $\left|t-\dfrac{\pi}{w_0\theta}n\right|\ll\dfrac{\pi}{2w_0\theta}$, a better approximation is
$$x(t)\approx x_0\,\cos(w_0t)+\frac{v_0}{w_0}\,\sin(w_0 t)+\frac{F}{2mw_0^2}\,\sin(w_0t)-\frac{F}{2mw_0}\,\left(t-\frac{\pi}{w_0\theta}n\right)\,\cos(w_0t)\,.$$
If $\left|t-\dfrac{\pi}{w_0\theta}n\right|$ is approximately in the same order as $\dfrac{\pi}{2w_0\theta}$, then the estimate (#) is good.